# Importing CSV files in R leads to unnecessary variables & observations

Tags: r, csv, xlsx

Here are the files I'm trying to import:

[Data](https://files.fm/u/despc7qy)

Included are two files, xlsx and CSV, that represent the same dataset. Though they represent the same information, I get different results when I import them into R. Via the read_excel(file.choose()) command, I can correctly import the xlsx file correctly, but if I use the read.csv(file.choose(), sep=";") command on the CSV file, I get unnecessary additional observations and variables. I only saved the Excel file as a comma separated values files (.csv) so R should actually construct the same data frames. What did I do wrong?

Comment: R is reading it in correctly. Excel is saving it with over 300 blank columns. Try this: in Excel, highlight the 314 columns (or more) to the right of `RELY` and right-click "Delete"; repeat with the 52 (or so) rows under your last `ZURN` row. Then save and import into R. (This is a case of [gigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out), where R is reading in what the file contains. Excel thought it was doing things right, since at least one of those empty cells used to have something.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There was indeed a larger data set below the data set that is now visible. I did try the delete method and it worked! I thought that deleting the cell contents was enough, but you actually do have to delete all the cells that have contained any sort of information. Thanks again for the solution!

Comment: @r2evans: I think this question should have an answer or someone should search for a duplicate. Answering should be easier.

Comment: There has ***got*** to be previous-art on this! I am not the first to experience this problem, and I can*not* be the first to suggest this as a workaround/solution (Really??)